# Videobackground and Button - Mobile

Tags: python, templates, responsive-design, flask

I have built [this app](http://finnfrotscher.pythonanywhere.com/) on `Flask`. There is no mobile support right now. Because the video load time is rather high, I want to serve the same videos but with a different resolution, cut and filetype when the page is opened on a handheld.

My questions:

1. What file types do I have to serve for mobile?
2. Should I build mobile detection into Python/Flask and serve two different templates, or build a responsive template that switches video type after measuring screen width?
3. How do I do 2?

Comment: Sorry, but your questions are to broad to be answered here. You should find a nice book or tutorial for Responsive Webdesign. Maybe a good starter: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-tutorials/

Comment: What do you mean by videoload too high?

Comment: I mean that a video is about 1mb and that is too much for mobil.

Comment: @KlausD. I know the basics about Responsive Webdesign. I have worked with bootstrap and build for example [link](http://frankaherwig.de). I just dont know the <right> way to solve this specific problem

Comment: Please [**edit this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29645375/edit) rather than opening new ones - there is guidance in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask